# Get and set programmatically keyboard shortcuts for languages switching on Windows

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi, keyboard-shortcuts

My desktop application runs on Windows 7/8. Several keyboard layouts are enabled in the OS.

Is there a way to get and set programmatically values of system keyboard shortcuts for switching between languages and also for switching to a certain language (like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to switch between languages, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to switch to English, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to switch to Dutch and so on).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get some information using the SystemParametersInfo function. Check it here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you! I've found the useful SETLANGTOGGLE parameter for setting the hot key set for switching between input languages. But there are still no getter and no parameters for turning on a certain language.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current settings, you could examine system registry, namely:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Toggle\
```

At least, in my Win10 environment I have *Language Hotkey* (if does not exist, fallback to equivalent *Hotkey*) and *Layout Hotkey* there, with values **1** (Alt + Shift), **2** (Ctrl + Shift), or **4** (Grave accent) set.
Playing around with it must help.

Comment: Sadly, if you change registry value you'll have to logout+login to it to make effect :(